# ionic, ios, the build version can't be imported.... CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, application-loader

I get an error trying to send my ionic app .ipa file with Application Loader.

But my config.xml is clean...

```
[2016-08-05 12:51:14 CEST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “134” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number."
[2016-08-05 12:51:14 CEST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.67] in the Info.plist file
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The version need to be specified on the `widget` element in `config.xml`. The version on xml element is just for xml language.

You need to do something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>
```